# Определение имени процесса по окну

Tags: windows, файловая-система, процесс

Добрый день. Мне нужно узнать имя процесса в диспетчере задач, имея лишь его окно. В моем случае, если в принтере нет бумаги, он выдает такое окно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако я этот процесс в диспетчере найти не могу. Можно ли как-то узнать его имя иными способами и чтобы наверняка?
Скриншот диспетчера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Диспетчер задач:
Вкладка "Приложения" -> Выбрать Ваше окно -> ПКМ -> "Перейти к процессу".
Имя выделенного процесса - то, что ищете.